# Como hacer una consulta que traiga datos diferentes en base a un dato dado

Tags: mysql, sql

Como hacer una consulta para traer las personas que vivan en un país diferente al país de una persona dada en MySql
Tengo las siguientes tablas:

PERSONAS, CIUDADES, DIVISIONES, PAISES, TIPODIVISION, IDIOMAS

```
--
-- Table structure for table `ciudades`
--
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `ciudades`;

CREATE TABLE `ciudades` (
  `IDCiu` int NOT NULL,
  `NomCiu` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Poblacion` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `IDDiv` int DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`IDCiu`),
  KEY `fk_IDDiv_idx` (`IDDiv`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_IDDiv` FOREIGN KEY (`IDDiv`) REFERENCES `divisiones` (`IDDiv`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

--
-- Dumping data for table `ciudades`
--
INSERT INTO `ciudades` 
VALUES (1,'Montería',490935,1),
       (2,'Cereté',94935,1),
       (3,'Sahagún',90494,1),
       (4,'Sincelejo',277773,3),
       (5,'Coveñas',17091,3),
       (6,'Corozal',53291,3),
       (7,'Barranquilla',1206000,2),
       (8,'Baranoa',55178,2),
       (9,'Soledad',683486,2),
       (10,'Toronto',2093000,4),
       (11,'Kingston',136685,4),
       (12,'Hamilton',579200,4),
       (13,'Vancouver',675218,5),
       (14,'Victoria',92141,5),
       (15,'Kelowna',132084,5),
       (16,'Edmonton',981280,6),
       (17,'Calgary',1336000,6),
       (18,'Banff',7847,6),
       (19,'Mejillones',852213,7),
       (20,'Sierra Gorda',5294,7),
       (21,'Talta',259863,7),
       (22,'Los Andes',25436,8),
       (23,'La Ligua',89631,8),
       (24,'Quillota',78526,8),
       (25,'Talca',8521,9),
       (26,'Curicó',4528,9),
       (27,'Constitución',4526,9),
       (28,'Múnich',1472000,10),
       (29,'Núremberg',518365,10),
       (30,'Augsburgo',295135,10),
       (31,'Mitte',52369,11),
       (32,'Schöneberg',85961,11),
       (33,'Spandau',12587,11),
       (34,'Altona',458235,12),
       (35,'Bergedorf',123548,12),
       (36,'Eimsbüttel',321648,12),
       (37,'Trinidad',166262,13),
       (38,'Riberalta',114869,13),
       (39,'Guayaramerin',51188,13),
       (40,'Sacaba',172466,14),
       (41,'Quillacollo',120356,14),
       (42,'Vinto',50287,14),
       (43,'Uyuni',14890,15),
       (44,'Arampampa',640,15),
       (45,'Colquechaca',7026,15);

--
-- Table structure for table `divisiones`
--
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `divisiones`;

CREATE TABLE `divisiones` (
  `IDDiv` int NOT NULL,
  `NomDiv` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Extensión` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `IDPais` int DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`IDDiv`),
  KEY `fk_IDPais_idx` (`IDPais`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_IDPais` FOREIGN KEY (`IDPais`) REFERENCES `paises` (`IDPais`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

--
-- Dumping data for table `divisiones`
--
INSERT INTO `divisiones` 
VALUES (1,'Córdoba',1,1),
       (2,'Atlántico',2,1),
       (3,'Sucre',3,1),
       (4,'Ontario',4,2),
       (5,'Columbia Británica',5,2),
       (6,'Alberta',6,2),
       (7,'Antofagasta',7,3),
       (8,'Valparaíso',8,3),
       (9,'Maule',9,3),
       (10,'Baviera',10,4),
       (11,'Berlín',11,4),
       (12,'Hamburgo',12,4),
       (13,'Beni',13,5),
       (14,'Cochabamba',14,5),
       (15,'Potosí',15,5);

--
-- Table structure for table `paises`
--
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `paises`;

CREATE TABLE `paises` (
  `IDPais` int NOT NULL,
  `NomPais` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `IDIdioma` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `IDTipo` int DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`IDPais`),
  KEY `fk_IDIdioma_idx` (`IDIdioma`),
  KEY `fk_IdTipo_idx` (`IDTipo`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_IDIdioma` FOREIGN KEY (`IDIdioma`) REFERENCES `idiomas` (`IDIdioma`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_IdTipo` FOREIGN KEY (`IDTipo`) REFERENCES `tipodivision` (`IDTipo`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

--
-- Dumping data for table `paises`
--
INSERT INTO `paises` 
VALUES (1,'Colombia',1,1),
       (2,'Canadá',2,2),
       (3,'Chile',1,3),
       (4,'Alemania',3,4),
       (5,'Bolivia',1,1);

--
-- Table structure for table `personas`
--
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `personas`;

CREATE TABLE `personas` (
  `IDPer` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `NomPer` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Direccion` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Telefono` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LugRes` int NOT NULL,
  `FechaNac` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `LugNac (IDCiu)` int NOT NULL,
  `correo` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`IDPer`),
  KEY `fk_LugNac_idx` (`LugNac (IDCiu)`),
  KEY `lugresFk_idx` (`LugRes`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_LugNac` FOREIGN KEY (`LugNac (IDCiu)`) REFERENCES `ciudades` (`IDCiu`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `lugresFk` FOREIGN KEY (`LugRes`) REFERENCES `ciudades` (`IDCiu`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=26 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

--
-- Dumping data for table `personas`
--
INSERT INTO `personas` 
VALUES (1,'Ascensión Otero','Carretera Ainara Galván','7864251',1,'1998-03-25',1,'AOtero@softcaribbean.com'),
       (2,'Evita Montaña','191 Barrows Plains','7845263',1,'1988-06-16',1,'EMontaña@softcaribbean.com'),
       (3,'Sol Ruperta','307 Sedrick Gateway','7895623',1,'1955-02-08',1,'SRuperta@softcaribbean.com'),
       (4,'Celia Goicoechea','8761 Fritsch Hill','7528514',8,'1975-05-27',8,'CGoicoechea@softcaribbean.com'),
       (5,'Cesar Sáenz','691 Fadel Tunnel','7962325',9,'1984-10-12',9,'CSaenz@softcaribbean.com'),
       (6,'Lucio Galan','507 Letha Falls','7412583',9,'1966-12-28',9,'LGalan@softcaribbean.com'),
       (7,'Isidoro Augusto','2435 Walter Rapids','7325689',2,'1999-07-30',2,'IAugusto@softcaribbean.com'),
       (8,'Máxima Eliana','6849 Bernier Greens','7143695',3,'1989-11-01',3,'MEliana@softcaribbean.com'),
       (9,'Áurea Morante','6103 Cayla','7258614',3,'1995-12-07',4,'AMorante@softcaribbean.com'),
       (10,'Yago Márquez','3977 Leonora','7742556',4,'1996-06-10',3,'YMarquez@softcaribbean.com'),
       (11,'Lucho Ferreras','51556 Ferry','7126459',5,'1998-01-09',6,'LFerreras@softcaribbean.com'),
       (12,'Consuela Lillo','369 Anderson','7125469',6,'1993-08-25',5,'CLillo@softcaribbean.com'),
       (13,'Agustín Mendizábal','7313 Anya','7823623',7,'1999-09-09',7,'AMendizabal@softcaribbean.com'),
       (14,'Angela May','8969 Hyman','14256348',10,'1999-10-01',18,'AMay@softcaribbean.com'),
       (15,'Natalie Maddox','02064 Hartmann Centers','142536985',12,'1998-10-02',15,'NMaddox@softcaribbean.com'),
       (16,'Angela Miller','655 Powlowski','14785693',11,'1999-10-05',11,'AMiller@softcaribbean.com'),
       (17,'Jonathan Myers','28173 Greenfelder','14321568',17,'1998-12-09',17,'JMyers@softcaribbean.com'),
       (18,'Sharon Duran','4955 Jaskolski','14561237',16,'1996-03-03',16,'SDuran@softcaribbean.com'),
       (19,'Ryan Vargas','3429 Marco Vista','14875621',15,'1999-07-29',15,'RVargas@softcaribbean.com'),
       (20,'Gerhild Graf','72859 Porter','015189',30,'1971-12-25',30,'GGraf@softcaribbean.com'),
       (21,'Zdravko Sontag','927 Dudley Hollow','015128',32,'1975-10-17',33,'ZSontag@softcaribbean.com'),
       (22,'Erich Schuster','34435 Blair','015286',34,'1986-07-26',39,'ESchuster@softcaribbean.com'),
       (23,'Heidi Tröst','708 Nathaniel','053967',36,'1945-05-12',36,'HTröst@softcaribbean.com'),
       (24,'Sinaida Trommler','429 Jarrett','05489',39,'1999-03-01',39,'STrommler@softcaribbean.com'),
       (25,'Linus Bärer','69812 Tianna','05578',37,'1997-12-25',37,'LBarer@softcaribbean.com');
```

por ejemplo aquí tengo el codigo para traer personas que vivan en el pais con ID = 1

```html
SELECT DISTINCT p.NomPer, pa.NomPais
 FROM personas p, ciudades c, divisiones d, paises pa
 WHERE  p.LugRes = c.IDCiu
 AND c.IDDiv = d.IDDiv
 AND d.IDPais = pa.IDPais
 AND d.IDPais= 1;
```

forenkey (LugNac y LugRes ) references CIUDADES (IDCiu)
IDDiv de ciudades es llave foránea con referencia a la tabla DIVISIONES, IDPais de divisiones, es llave foránea con referencia a la tabla PAISES, IDTipo de paises es llave foránea a la tabla TIPODIVISION

pero no comprendo como aplicar eso a la pregunta inicial ¿Si por ejemplo quisiera traer las personas que vivan en un pais diferente a la persona con IDPer=1?

Comment: forenkey (LugNac y LugRes ) references CIUDADES (IDCiu),
IDDiv de ciudades es llave foránea con referencia a la tabla DIVISIONES,
IDPais de divisiones, es llave foránea con referencia a la tabla PAISES,
IDTipo de paises es llave foránea a la tabla TIPODIVISION

Comment: Arregla bien tu pregunta, coloca (Sin fotos) la estructura de tus tablas para poder ayudarte.

Comment: ya lo cambie por codigo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero vamos a revisar la consulta que ya tienes que muestra todas las personas y el país al que pertenecen. Pero está con una sintaxis obsoleta y que se presta a confusión, así que pasamos del estándar SQL-86 al estándar SQL-92 (30 años de este estándar y siguen enseñando el anterior).

Con los cambios, la consulta queda así.

```
SELECT p.NomPer, 
       pa.NomPais
 FROM personas   p
 JOIN ciudades   c  ON p.LugRes = c.IDCiu
 JOIN divisiones d  ON c.IDDiv  = d.IDDiv 
 JOIN paises     pa ON d.IDPais = pa.IDPais
 WHERE d.IDPais = 1;
```

Ahora podemos identificar más fácilmente cuales son las condiciones para unir las tablas y cuales son los filtros de la consulta. Podemos ver también que la condición del WHERE es incorrecta porque no cumple lo que pides. Así que lo que hacemos es usar una consulta similar para obtener el país de la persona 1 y decir que quieres a todas las personas que no vivan en ese país.

```
SELECT p.NomPer, 
       pa.NomPais
 FROM personas   p
 JOIN ciudades   c  ON p.LugRes = c.IDCiu
 JOIN divisiones d  ON c.IDDiv  = d.IDDiv 
 JOIN paises     pa ON d.IDPais = pa.IDPais
 WHERE d.IDPais NOT IN(  SELECT d.IDPais
                         FROM personas   p
                         JOIN ciudades   c  ON p.LugRes = c.IDCiu
                         JOIN divisiones d  ON c.IDDiv  = d.IDDiv
                         WHERE p.IDPer = 1);
```

La subconsulta es muy similar pero no necesitamos la tabla paises porque solo requerimos la llave que está en la tabla divisiones. Obviamente, para hacer más flexible este código, lo ideal sería que conviertas ese 1 en un parámetro/variable y que se pueda modificar su valor según se requiera.

Comment: Comprendo, muchisimas gracias por tomarte el tiempo y explicar la direncia en estandares, me has ayudando mucho